# What is the complexity of Longest increasing sub sequence algorithm without dynamic programming and how to compute it

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

This is the code from GeeksForGeeks of LIS.

```
 /* To make use of recursive calls, this function must return
   two things:
   1) Length of LIS ending with element arr[n-1]. We use
  max_ending_here for this purpose
   2) Overall maximum as the LIS may end with an element
  before arr[n-1] max_ref is used this purpose.
  The value of LIS of full array of size n is stored in 
  *max_ref which is our final result */
int _lis( int arr[], int n, int *max_ref)
 {
/* Base case */
if (n == 1)
    return 1;

// 'max_ending_here' is length of LIS ending with arr[n-1]
int res, max_ending_here = 1; 

/* Recursively get all LIS ending with arr[0], arr[1] ... 
   arr[n-2]. If   arr[i-1] is smaller than arr[n-1], and 
   max ending with arr[n-1] needs to be updated, then 
   update it */
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    res = _lis(arr, i, max_ref);
    if (arr[i-1] < arr[n-1] && res + 1 > max_ending_here)
        max_ending_here = res + 1;
 }

// Compare max_ending_here with the overall max. And 
// update the overall max if needed
if (*max_ref < max_ending_here)
   *max_ref = max_ending_here;

// Return length of LIS ending with arr[n-1]
return max_ending_here;
}

// The wrapper function for _lis()
int lis(int arr[], int n)
 {
  // The max variable holds the result
int max = 1;

// The function _lis() stores its result in max
_lis( arr, n, &max );

// returns max
return max;
}

 /* Driver program to test above function */
int main()
 {
   int arr[] = { 10, 22, 9, 33, 21, 50, 41, 60 };
   int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
   printf("Length of LIS is %d\n",  lis( arr, n ));
   return 0;
 }
```

This is the tree .How to compute complexity of the algorithm through it ? Is there are some proper methods of computing complexity of such algorithms or programmers compute it intuitively and after applying dynamic programming how the complexity is reduced  to 0(n^2)

```
                 lis(4)   

             /       |      \
        lis(3)      lis(2)    lis(1)  
       /     \        /         
   lis(2)  lis(1)   lis(1) 
   /    
lis(1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the complexity of the solution without dynamic programming for an input size **n** = `f(n)`

Now, observe the recurrence:
f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + f(n-3) + ... + f(1)
where recursively f(n-1) = f(n-2) + f(n-3) + ... f(1)

Clearly, we can observe that f(n) = 2*f(n-1)
So our compact recurrence relation is `f(n) = 2*f(n-1)`

f(n) = 2*f(n-1)
f(n-1) = 2*f(n-2)
...
f(2) = 2*f(1)
f(1) = 2*f(0)

Among the above equations, multiply the ith equation by 2^(i-1) and then add all the equations. We clearly then have f(n) = (2^n)*f(0) = O(2^n)

Hence the complexity is exponential = `O(2^n)`

Now let's look at what happens when we use dynamic programming. When we use DP, we are saving f(n) once we compute it, so that we don't compute it ever again in the recursion. That leaves us with:
f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + ... f(1)
but this time when the recursive call of f(n-1) computes f(n-2), f(n-3), etc. then we don't have to recompute it while calculating f(n).

So now, f(n) = n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... 1 which is `O(n^2)`
Hope this helps.